# EclipseFP - configuring because setup_config not present

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, eclipse-fp

I have installed Haskell platform and I wanted to also install EclipseFP. I followed some instructions online and I thought it was done, but when I type any character i get the following message:

> configuring because setup_config not present
>
> Resolving dependencies...
>
> Configuring proj1-0.1...

I have no idea what I must do now, but I hope somebody does.

Comment: EclipseFP is not maintained anymore, so I'd recommend you use another IDE for Haskell. If you keep seeing this error, it's because the configuration of the project doesn't succeed, which is often because of some mismatch between cabal versions, etc.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the quick response. Could you tell me some good IDE for Haskell?

Comment: IDE, supported by Ubuntu*

Comment: I use Leksah or Atom with the Haskell plugins.